# How to append data to file with write function?

Tags: r, file, append

I thought that snippet will do the trick:

```
f <- file("append2me.txt")

write(1:5,  ncolumns = 5, f)
write(6:10, ncolumns = 5, f, append = T)

close(f)

f <- file("append2me.txt")

print(readLines(f))
```

But the result is:

```
[1] "6 7 8 9 10"
```

Why is that?

Comment: Just to note, setting f as string works fine: `f <- "append2me.txt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is about how we open the file:

```
f <- file("append2me.txt", open = "a")
write(1:5,  ncolumns = 5, file = f)
write(6:10, ncolumns = 5, file = f)
close(f)

f1 <- file("append2me.txt", open = "r")
readLines(con = f1)
close(f1)
# [1] "1 2 3 4 5"  "6 7 8 9 10"
```

*write* is just a wrapper for *cat*, from cat manuals, see:

> **append**     logical. Only used if the argument `file` is the name of file (and not a connection or "`|cmd`"). If `TRUE` output will be appended to `file`; otherwise, it will overwrite the contents of `file`.